# Flatten and transform data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, observable-plot

Given this object (items per array is the same) :

```js
{
    force_x: [6, 7, 7],
    force_y: [2, 3, 4],
    timestamp: [0.08, 0.016, 0.024]
}
```

How could I use Javascript to create this for all keys except `timestamp` :

```js
{
    {mode: "force_x", value: 6, timestamp: 0.08},
    {mode: "force_x", value: 7, timestamp: 0.16},
    {mode: "force_x", value: 7, timestamp: 0.24},
    {mode: "force_y", value: 2, timestamp: 0.08},
    {mode: "force_y", value: 3, timestamp: 0.16},
    {mode: "force_y", value: 4, timestamp: 0.24},
}
```

Note that the `timestamp` array can be removed from the object, if it's easier to handle. The algorithm should not specify the `force_x` and `force_y` keys and do it automatically for each keys.

Comment: Can we handle `timestamp` differently than other keys? As in, can we explicitly use the key `timestamp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nice little one-liner:

```js
const data = {
    force_x: [6, 7, 7],
    force_y: [2, 3, 4],
    timestamp: [0.08, 0.016, 0.024]
};

const {  timestamp, ...props } = data;

const result = Object.keys(props).flatMap((mode) => props[mode].map((value, i) => ({ mode, value, timestamp: timestamp[i] })));

console.log(result);
```

First, we exclude `timestamp` from the data.
Then for each key, we need to map it to its "expanded form". To do this, we map each value of the key to an object. While mapping, we get the index of the element and use that to get the corresponding timestamp for the object. However, this will give us an array of the form `[[{ ... }, { ... }], ...]`, so we have to flatten it. Fortunately, there is a shortcut for us and that is `flatMap`, which is equivalent to using `map` and then `flat`.

Comment: Very neat! And thanks for the detailed information.